# Do Dataproc have a resource allocation limit per job

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

Let say I have a Dataproc cluster of 100 worker nodes with a certain spec.

When I submitted a job to dataproc, is there a usage allocation limit to each job

e.g. job A cannot run more than 50% of all total nodes

Do we have this kind of limit? Or any job can allocate all resource of the cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such per job limit on DataProc. One job could use all resources of YARN, and that's usually the default config for various job types on DataProc. But users can set per job limit as they want, e.g., for Spark, disable dynamic allocation, set the number of executors and the memory size of each executors.